# Is there a way to force gnuplot to make everything bigger?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave

I'm trying to use octave to draw root locuses and apparently the code for drawing it was written in the early 2000s so everything is far too small to see. I can't figure out how to modify everything to be at a visible size, and I shouldn't have to.

How do I configure gnuplot to make everything be a visible size by default? I can't find any info on how to configure it with google.

Edit:

Here's the code:

```
pkg load control;
s = tf('s');
rlocus((s+10)/(s*(s+1)*(s+20)))
```

That produces a plot that looks like this:

[image: A plot with tiny crosses and circles that are too small to see without zooming in]

Comment: a) you don't have to use gnuplot just because the code is old. b) yes there is, how exactly depends on your code c) you are right you shouldn't have to - the defaults tend to be very sensible. if it looks weird, it's probably something to do with the code itself. d) basically, show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the code. This may not be a full answer for you, but I'm writing this in the form of an answer in order to post images...

Your graph looks a bit weird indeed for a default graph. This is what your code produces on my system (Linux Mint, Octave v6.2.0) by default (i.e. using the qt toolkit):

[image]

It would be helpful to have some more information:

- What operating system are you using?
- What version of octave are you using?
- What graphics toolkit are you using? (type `graphics_toolkit` in the octave console), and if this is not the default `qt` one, why is this the case?

Having said that, if you're happy to specify some graph settings yourself, it is certainly possible to specify fontsizes etc. E.g.

```
pkg load control;
s = tf('s');
rlocus((s+10)/(s*(s+1)*(s+20)))
set( gca, 'fontsize', 20 )
Pos = get( gcf, 'position' ); set( gcf, 'position', Pos + [0, 0, 500, 200] )
```

[image]

Comment: I get similar results to you running on Windows with Octave 6.2.0.  Both qt and gnuplot toolkits produce similar plots. (gnuplot actually has larger default fonts it seems).